# Keep combobox selected value after program is closed WPF C#

Tags: c#, xaml

I have a combobox and I want the value that the user selects to stay selected after the program is closed and re-opened.

```
        <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" 
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                  Width="120" Foreground="White" SelectionChanged="comboBox_SelectionChanged" BorderBrush="White" Margin="415,89,0,0" Grid.Row="2" Style="{DynamicResource ComboBoxStyle1}" Grid.Column="1">
            <ComboBoxItem x:Name="DX" 
                          TabIndex="0" 
                          Content="  Directx" Opacity="0.90" Foreground="White" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="#FF752020" Background="#FF224755" OpacityMask="#FFF90909" Style="{DynamicResource ItemStyle}" Height="20"/>
            <ComboBoxItem x:Name="OGL" 
                          TabIndex="1" 
                          Content="  OpenGL" Background="#FF1C8080" Foreground="White" Opacity="0.90" BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" BorderBrush="#FFF3E109" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Style="{DynamicResource ItemStyle}" Height="19"/>

        </ComboBox>
```

Comment: In short, you have to save the setting in a file, then load that when starting and set the value back.

Comment: Check out [Application Settings Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/application-settings-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) for some reading and links about some built-in tools to make it easy to persist app-level settings.  (It's just one way to solve this, and the link outlines some limitations too.  But it's generally easy to set up and use.)